# Div not showing Hover function correctly

Tags: css, html

I have two div's inside of a containing div.

The first of the two will have a word used as a menu item and the second will hold a background color.

I created a hover style for the background that will change the opacity of that div when the menu item is moused over.

My problem is that hover is only enabled when the mouse is right on the edges of the div. As soon as my mouse moves a little into the interior of the div, it reverts back to the original opacity.

My style:

```
.menuItemBG {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#4281b6;
    height:100%;

    /* These three lines are for transparency in all browsers. */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
    opacity:.1;
    position: absolute;
}
.menuItemBG:hover {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#4281b6;
    height:100%;

    /* These three lines are for transparency in all browsers. */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity:.2;
    position: absolute;
}
.menuItemTitle{
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

HTLML:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:208px; height:30px;">
    <div class="menuItemBG"></div>
    <div class="menuItemTitle">Test Item</div>
 </div>
```

Can't seem to pinpoint my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over the `menuItemTitle`, you are no longer hovering over `menuItemBG` because they are siblings in the DOM. You can switch the `:hover` to the div that contains them, and apply the styles to `menuItemBG` that way. If you give the containing div the class `menuItem`, you can do:

```
.menuItem:hover .menuItemBG {
    /* These three lines are for transparency in all browsers. */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity:.2;
}
```

Notice I did not repeat the CSS that applies regularly to `.menuItemBG`. It is not needed. So then add the class `menuItem` to your containing div:

```
<div class="menuItem">
    <div class="menuItemBG"></div>
    <div class="menuItemTitle">Test Item</div>
</div>
```

You can move that inline CSS you had for `.menuItem` to your stylesheet quite easily now. It works either way, but moving it to the stylesheet is cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
.menuItem {
    position: relative;
    width: 208px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fYQfX/1

Comment: I made some edits that apply to stylistic suggestions. Cheers!